# Brand New Hyundai Santa Fe 2016 2.4 L uses 15 L/100KM

Tags: hyundai, santa-fe

Need your help guys, I bought a brand new Santa Fe 2016 engine 2.4L 4WD Automatic. The problem I am facing is excessive fuel consumption. It is using 15L/100KM of gasoline and it is too much because this size of engine should use only 9.4L/100KM.

Please help guys; I dont know what's going on. Thanks in advance for you responding.

Comment: The car should be under warranty. I suggest you take it to the dealer and have them investigate it.

Comment: Tell me about your diving habits. People who complain about bad fuel economy tend to be aggressive drives who haven't been told they are.

Answer (score 5):

15L/100 km is around 15.6 mpg, which is lower than the [19-25 mpg](https://www.fueleconomy.gov/feg/noframes/36212.shtml) rating provided by fueleconomy.gov for this Santa Fe.

Given that the car is brand new, it should still be under manufacturer warranty. You should have the car inspected by a dealership.